# USB mouse stopped working after reboot

Tags: usb, mouse

I have a wireless usb mouse which was working up until two days ago, then my laptop ran out of battery and when I charged and turned it back on, it wasn't working anymore.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and when I run `lsusb`, the usb is recognized on Bus 002 Device 003

```
~ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:5a07 IMC Networks VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:3526 IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 3151:3020 YICHIP Wireless Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

However, it doesn't appear on `xinput`, and isn't working. I've recharged the mouse, changed the usb port, and rebooted the computer, but nothing worked.

Comment: Change the batteries. in the mouse.

Comment: You might need to do a power reset of the system by powering off the laptop, then holding in the power button for 30 seconds, then powering it back on.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks for the suggestion, it wasn't something I had tried before, but unfortunately it didn't solve the issue

Comment: @waltinator The batteries are new and charged, this shouldn't be the issue. Also, the batteries aren't removable, so if it was there wouldn't be much I could do

Comment: One other question, have you tried the mouse on another computer just to eliminate the mouse as the issue?

Comment: @Terrance I don't have another computer available to test it right now, but I eventually solved it and posted the solution. It was a driver problem.

Comment: Nice job!  +1  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after hours of messing around, I've been able to solve the issue:

After connecting the usb dongle, wait a few minutes, then restart the driver

```
sudo rmmod usbhid
sudo modprobe usbhid
```

And it solved the issue for me.

I had tried this before, but without waiting enough after. I will now attempt to explain why this happened, and why this solution works:

- First thing I noticed was that, if I ran `lsusb` as soon as I connect the dongle, it takes a while (around a minute on average) to finish the output.
- The mouse is on Bus 02, and while interface 0 is bound to the driver usbhid, interface 1 is unbound. This is shown on the output of `lsusb -t`:

  ```
  /:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
  /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
      |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
      |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=, 12M
  /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
      |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
          |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
          |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
          |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
          |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
          |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
  ```
- However, when I try to bind it with `echo 2-1:1.1 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/bind` as root, it returns the error `bash: echo: write error: Connection timed out`. This is the only part I haven't been able to figure out why it doesn't work.
- When I disconnect and reconnect the dongle, it generates these lines on `dmesg`:

  ```
  [ 8390.096097] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
  [ 8395.540313] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
  [ 8395.714320] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=3151, idProduct=3020, bcdDevice= 0.02
  [ 8395.714336] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
  [ 8395.714340] usb 2-1: Product: Wireless Device
  [ 8395.714344] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: YICHIP
  [ 8395.730764] input: YICHIP Wireless Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/0003:3151:3020.0004/input/input18
  [ 8395.789546] hid-generic 0003:3151:3020.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v2.00 Keyboard [YICHIP Wireless Device] on usb-0000:00:10.0-1/input0
  [ 8421.452199] usbhid 2-1:1.1: can't add hid device: -110
  [ 8421.452241] usbhid: probe of 2-1:1.1 failed with error -110
  ```

  usbhid fails to add interface 1 with error -110, which according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13661508) answer means "Timeout expired before the transfer completed". My hypothesis is that since there is a delay between connection the dongle and it being identified by `lsusb`, it is probably taking too long to respond to usbhid and it gives error -110.

If this hypothesis is correct, then initializing usbhid after the usb connection is properly established should work, and it indeed does. This doesn't guarantee my explanation is correct, nor does it explain why I can't just bind the driver to the interface manually, so it would be interesting if there is another explanation of what's going on here. But the solution of restarting the driver works, so I'll consider this a satisfactory answer for now.